# Django redirect - why is page HTML appearing as URL param?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm writing an app that includes user registration and login functionality.  After a successful login/registration action, the user is to be redirected to `user.html`

Right now, the entire HTML text is showing up as a URL param, which is throwing an error 404

My view code for view handling:

```
def index(request):
  return render(request, "app/index.html")

def user(request):
  return render(request, "app/user.html")

def userLogin(request):
  print "Loggin In!"
  loginUser = authenticate(username = request.POST["username"], password = request.POST["password"])
  print loginUser.username
  print loginUser.is_staff
  if loginUser is not None:
    if loginUser.is_active:
      login(request, loginUser)
      return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(user))
```

and my urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns("",
  url(r'^$', views.index, name = "index"),
  url(r'^user/$', views.user),
  url(r'^registerNewUser/$', views.registerNewUser),
  url(r'^userLogin/$', views.userLogin),
)
```

On redirect, this is the message that shows:

```
Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
^app/ ^$ [name='index']
^app/ ^user/$
^app/ ^registerNewUser/$
^app/ ^userLogin/$


The current URL, app/<html><head><title>User Landing Page</title><link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "/static/css/jquery-ui.min.css" ><link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "/static/css/main.css"><script type = "text/javascript" src = "/static/js/jquery.js"></script><script type = "text/javascript" src = "/static/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script><script type = "text/javascript" src = "/static/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script><script type = "text/javascript" src = "/static/js/csrfSetup.js"></script></head><body>User is logged</body></html>, didn't match any of these.
```

What do I need to do in order to have the HTML be rendered upon a successful login?

Answer (score 1):

Please, read again the doc of django and the [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse) method:

in your views.py

```
def index(request):
  return render(request, "app/index.html")

def user(request):
  return render(request, "app/user.html")

def userLogin(request):
    loginUser = authenticate(username = request.POST["username"], password = request.POST["password"])     
    if loginUser is not None:
      if loginUser.is_active:
        login(request, loginUser)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("user")) #See that! it's a url name!
    return HttpResponse(reverse("index")) # What happens if can't log in?
```

in your urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns("",
  url(r'^$', views.index, name = "index"),
  url(r'^user/$', views.user, name="user"), #Note the "user"!
  url(r'^registerNewUser/$', views.registerNewUser),
  url(r'^userLogin/$', views.userLogin),
)
```

Comment: You were almost correct, check my answer for the solution that worked for me.  Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that worked for me.  It consisted of using `reverse()` with `HttpResponse()`.

Specifically,

```
def index(request):
  return render(request, "app/index.html")

def user(request):
  if request.user.is_authenticated:
    if not request.user.is_staff:
        return render(request, "app/user.html")
    else:
        return render(request, "app/admin.html")

  else: 
    return HttpResponse(reverse(index))

def userLogin(request):
  loginUser = authenticate(username = request.POST["username"], password = request.POST["password"])

  if loginUser is not None:
    if not loginUser.is_active:
        loginUser.is_active = True
        loginUser.save()

    login(request, loginUser)

    #Note HttpResponse and unquoted user method
    return HttpResponse(reverse(user)) 
else:
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({"login" : "failed"}))
```

combined with the following `urls.py` configuration

```
urlpatterns = patterns("",
  url(r'^$', views.index, name = "index"),
  url(r'^$', views.user, name = "user"),
  url(r'^user/$', views.user, name = "user"),
  url(r'^registerNewUser/$', views.registerNewUser),
  url(r'^userLogin/$', views.userLogin),
)
```

got the redirect working to the relevant pages after a successful login or registration.